# Скрипт "ходячего человека" не работает, в чем просчет?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function(){

var curr;
var swapped = 0;
var $W = $(window);
var $man = $('.footer-walk-man');
var mw = $man.width();
var max = $W.width() - mw;
var time = $W.width()/(mw*1.2);
var walk = {
    init: function (){
        walk.right();
        walk.counters();
        $W.on('resize', function (){
            max = walk.getMax();
            time = $W.width()/mw;
        });
    },
    getMax: function (){
        return $W.width() - mw;
    },
    swap: function(){
        swapped = swapped ? false : true;
        curr = curr == '180deg' ? '0deg' : '180deg';
        TweenMax.set($man, {transform: 'rotateY('+ curr +')'});
    },
    left: function (){
        curr = swapped ? '0deg' : '180deg';
        TweenMax.set($man, {transform: 'rotateY('+ curr +')'});
        TweenMax.to(
            $man,
            time,
            {
                left: 0,
                ease: Power0.easeNone,
                onComplete: function(){
                    TweenLite.killTweensOf($man);
                    walk.right();
                }
            }
        );
    },
    right: function (){
        curr = swapped ? '180deg' : '0deg';
        TweenMax.set($man, {transform: 'rotateY('+ curr +')'});
        TweenMax.to(
            $man,
            time,
            {
                left: max,
                ease: Power0.easeNone,
                onComplete: function(){
                    TweenLite.killTweensOf($man);
                    walk.left();
                }
            }
        );
    },
    counters: function (){
        var $metr, $cal,
            _timer;
        $metr = $('.footer-walk-metr');
        $cal = $('.footer-walk-cal');

        clearInterval(_timer);
        _timer = setInterval(function (){
            $metr.text(parseInt($metr.text())+1);
            $cal.text(Number(parseFloat($cal.text())+0.087).toFixed(2));
        }, 1000);
    }
};
walk.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="footer-walk">
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-walk-man"><img src=".gif" alt=""></div>
        <div class="footer-walk-info">
            <div class="footer-walk-info-in">
                <div class="footer-walk-title">Пока вы находитесь на сайте,</div>
                <div>человечек уже прошел <b class="footer-walk-metr"></b> м</div>
                <div>и, между прочим, потратил <b class="footer-walk-cal"></b> ккал</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот нашел код по Ходящему человеку который сжигает калорий. Только вот он не передает ничего в классы див не движется блок с картинкой и не цифры не изменяются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы человечек двигался, Вы задаете `left` от `0` до `max`, поэтому самому человечку нужно задать css св-во `position:relative` или `position:absolute` (на статику `left` \ `right` не действует).

Изначально в `$metr` и `$cal` пустота. Стоит задать какое-то стартовое значение (например просто `0`):

```js
var curr;
var swapped = 0;
var $W = $(window);
var $man = $('.footer-walk-man');
var mw = $man.width();
var max = $W.width() - mw;
var time = $W.width()/(mw*1.2);

var walk = {
    init: function (){
        walk.right();
        walk.counters();
        $W.on('resize', function (){
            max = walk.getMax();
            time = $W.width()/mw;
        });
    },
    getMax: function (){
        return $W.width() - mw;
    },
    swap: function(){
        swapped = swapped ? false : true;
        curr = curr == '180deg' ? '0deg' : '180deg';
        TweenMax.set($man, {transform: 'rotateY('+ curr +')'});
    },
    left: function (){
        curr = swapped ? '0deg' : '180deg';
        TweenMax.set($man, {transform: 'rotateY('+ curr +')'});
        TweenMax.to(
            $man,
            time,
            {
                left: 0,
                ease: Power0.easeNone,
                onComplete: function(){
                    TweenLite.killTweensOf($man);
                    walk.right();
                }
            }
        );
    },
    right: function (){
        curr = swapped ? '180deg' : '0deg';
        TweenMax.set($man, {transform: 'rotateY('+ curr +')'});
        TweenMax.to(
            $man,
            time,
            {
                left: max,
                ease: Power0.easeNone,
                onComplete: function(){
                    TweenLite.killTweensOf($man);
                    walk.left();
                }
            }
        );
    },
    counters: function (){
        var $metr, $cal,
            _timer;
      
        $metr = $('.footer-walk-metr');
        $cal = $('.footer-walk-cal');
      
      //console.log($metr.text());

        clearInterval(_timer);
        _timer = setInterval(function (){
            $metr.text(parseInt($metr.text())+1);
            $cal.text(Number(parseFloat($cal.text())+0.087).toFixed(2));
        }, 1000);
    }
};
  
walk.init();
```

```css
.footer-walk-man {
  width:150px; 
  position:relative;
}

.footer-walk-man img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="footer-walk">
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="footer-walk-man">
          <img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MelodicHelplessIsopod-max-1mb.gif" alt="">
      </div>
        <div class="footer-walk-info">
            <div class="footer-walk-info-in">
                <div class="footer-walk-title">Пока вы находитесь на сайте,</div>
                <div>человечек уже прошел <b class="footer-walk-metr">0</b> м</div>
                <div>и, между прочим, потратил <b class="footer-walk-cal">0</b> ккал</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! а по walk-man что бы он двигался влево до конца потом разворот и вправо вот в коде есть это но почему то не работает(

Comment: @Basszilla, не видно человечка))))

Comment: http://associirovan.kz/2018/07/19/test/
Не работает почему то на моем сайте( и цифры и человек не ходит
Даже в отдельном индексе на компе(

Comment: А можно что бы он двигался ?

Comment: @Basszilla, обновила и объяснила

Comment: Спасибо вам! большое и огромное)

Comment: associirovan.kz/2018/07/19/test У меня он все равно стоит и цифры не меняются как тут ( в чем различие хотя нету ошибок в консоли и ваши jquery я подключаю

Comment: @Basszilla, то что вы мое вставили у вас отображается картинкой http://prntscr.com/k89tsh. В консоли у вас 6 ошибок в других скриптах исправлять нужно. Стили челорвечку вы так и не задали

Comment: отлично сделал держи плюсик

Comment: Я нашел причину спасибо если js подключаю после div то работает)

Comment: Парни бомбим фитнес клубы и забираем халявные абонементы за это и не надо дешевить!) подберите каждый свой стиль! и удачи) и Спасибо Огромное HamSter!